# Cannot load data using force:recordData from my component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force-recorddata, custom-actions

I'm struggling to get fetch data from my component using Lightning Data Service.
My component is linked to a custom action to create a new record for a custom object.
Below is the error i get when the page load :

[image: Display error after clicking on the NEW record button]

---------------myComponent.cmp-----------------------

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<!--components attributes-->
<aura:attribute name="customObject" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="newCustomObject" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleCustomObject" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="customObjectError" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="customObjectRecordLoader"
    LayoutType="FULL"
    fields=""
    recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
    targetRecord="{!v.newCustomObject}"
    targetFields="{!v.simpleCustomObject}"
    targetError="{!v.customObjectError}"
    mode="EDIT"
/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.newCustomObjectError))}">
        <div class="recordError">
            <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" closable="true">
                {!v.newCustomObjectError}
            </ui:message>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

-------------------myComponentController.js--------------------------------------

```
({
 doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
  component.find("customObjectRecordLoader").getNewRecord(
   "Custom_Object__c", // objectApiName
   null, // recordTypeId
   false, // skip cache?
     $A.getCallback(function() {
       var rec = component.get("v.newCustomObject");
       var error = component.get("v.newCustomObjectError");
      if(error || (rec === null)) {
        console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
      }
      else {
        console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.sobjectType);
      }
    })
  );
 }
})
```

I really don't understand what's wrong with my code so thank a lot for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case sensitivity for `layoutType`.

FYI, you probably shouldn't include a null `fields` attribute if you have `layoutType` specified.

The `fields` attribute should be specified in conjunction with `layoutType` when you want fields that are absolutely needed, even if they were removed from the page layout

```
<force:recordData aura:id="customObjectRecordLoader"
    layoutType="FULL"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
    targetRecord="{!v.newCustomObject}"
    targetFields="{!v.simpleCustomObject}"
    targetError="{!v.customObjectError}"
    mode="EDIT"
/>
```